# Knowing that $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function and $G(s)$ is a generating function, prove $G(\phi(t))$ is also a characteristic function.

Tags: generating-functions, characteristic-functions

If $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function of a random variable $X$ and if $G(s)$ is the generating function of a random variable $Y$, $Y \in \{0,1,2,\dots,\}$, prove that $G(\phi(t))$ is also a characteristic function, and find its corresponding random variable.

I've already done some work but get stuck. 
According to the definition of the generating function and the property of the characteristic function:
$$ G(\phi(t))=E(\phi(t)^Y)=\sum_kP(Y=k)\phi(t)^k $$
$$ \phi(t)^k= E(e^{it\sum_{j=1}^{k}X_j})$$
And we also know
$$ G(\phi(t))=G(0) + G^{'}(0)\phi(t)+\frac{G^{''}(0)}{2!}\phi(t)^2+\dots+\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\phi(t)^k+\dots $$
Then 
$$ G(\phi(t))=\sum_{k}\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}E(e^{it\sum_{j=1}^{k}X_j}) $$

How can I show this $G(\phi(t))$ is a characteristic function?

Comment: this is equal to $\mathbb{E}[e^{it \sum_{j=1}^Y X_j}] = \phi_{S_Y}(t)$ where $S_Y = \sum_{j=1}^Y X_j$ and $X_j$ are iid copies of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ such that

- $X_1=X$ in distribution,
- $Y$ is independent of $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$.

Show that the characteristic function of the random variable

$$Z:=\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i$$

equals $G(\phi)$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm trying to do. $G(\phi(t))=\sum_{k}\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}E(e^{it\sum_{j=1}^{k}X_j})$. Here $\sum_{j=1}^{k}X_j$ is a new random variable $S_{k}$. Then $G(\phi(t))=\sum_{k}\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}E(e^{itS_{k}})$. But how can I get rid of the expectation in the sum? Is this equation correct? $\sum_{k}\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}E(e^{itS_{k}}) = \sum_{k}\frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}e^{itS_{k}} $

Comment: @KKKcat No, it's not correct; you cannot just drop the expectation. Note that $$\mathbb{E}e^{itS_k} = \mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{m=1}^k e^{it X_m} \right).$$ Now use independence

Comment: @saz So then $$\prod_{m=1}^k \mathbb E[e^{itX_m}] = \prod_{m=1}^k \mathbb E[e^{itX_1}] = \mathbb E[e^{itX_1}]^k,$$ but then what?

Comment: @Math1000 Well, did you follow my hint? (Your first comment suggest that you didn't) If so, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Following the hint, I have
$$
\mathbb E[e^{itZ}] = \mathbb E\left[e^{it\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i} \right] = \prod_{i-=1}^Y \mathbb E[e^{itX_i}] = \prod_{i=1}^Y \mathbb E[e^{itX_1}] = \mathbb E[e^{itX_i}]^Y,
$$
from which I do not see how to proceed..

Comment: @Math1000 The second "=" is wrong. Note that $Y$ is a random variable! You cannot just take it outside the expectation (you can see this, for instance, from the fact that the left-hand side of your equation is a constant whereas the right-hand side is a random variable). Further hint: Write $$\mathbb{E}\exp \left( it \sum_{m=1}^Y X_m \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y=k\}} \exp \left( it \sum_{m=1}^Y X_m \right) \right)= \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y=k\}} \exp \left( it \sum_{m=1}^k X_m \right) \right).$$ Interchange sum + expectation and use independence.

Comment: @saz It is late and I will have to pick this up tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @saz Following that hint I get $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(Y=k)\mathbb E[e^{itX_1}]^k. $$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, it is.